# Beta function in QFT renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, asymptotics

In order to know how the coupling constant depends on the energy scales,it is necessary to know the Beta function.Normally the Beta function is is calculated perturbatively. Now, my question is this:

1. the series that give the Beta function converges or, as I believe,it is only an asymptotic series?
2. if the series is only asymtotic, how do extract informations from it, such as that, for exemple, that the theory we are examining enjoys asymptotic freedom?

Comment: For SUSY Yang-Mills the beta function is known exactly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Beta_function_and_running_coupling.

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly examples where the beta function can be calculated exactly, while agreeing with the results for the corresponding loop expansion (a recent example is https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10174). So here it is not asymptotic. I doubt there is a general statement regarding the convergence in a generic QFT, but maybe somebody can add more detail. (Also, it is a very risky thing to "believe" something in physics without having at least some kind of proof or solid reasoning. But maybe you do?)